# Asp.net loads all dlls on startup causing BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP .NET 4.0 project which depends on two native dlls, lets call them `Native.Lib.dll` and `Native.Lib64.dll` (32 and 64 bit respectively). Our project is built as `AnyCPU` and we dynamically load one of the two native libs based on the value of `IntPtr.Size`.

The native libraries are installed same directory as the rest of the binaries. Whenever I run the project, I get:

> BadImageFormatExceptionCould not load file or assembly 'Native.Lib64'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
>   an incorrect format.

And when I switch IIS to 64 bit, it has the same complaint about 'Native.Lib'. From the research I have done, it looks like ASP.net loads all dlls in the directory on startup and blows up because of a "bitness" mismatch.

I have found that I can remove these binaries from the initial load in the `Web.config` file using `<remove assembly="Native.Lib"/>` and `<remove assembly="Native.Lib64"/>`, but I am worried that when it comes time to load these assemblies, they won't be able to load.

Furthermore, there are two other native assemblies already in the directory that ASP.net doesn't seem to have a problem with. (the developer that already solved this problem is no longer with the company). There are no `<remove>` tags in the config file for them, but ASP doesn't seem to mind.

Is there a way I can get ASP.net to ignore these files without removing them? If not, will the dlls be available when I call `Assembly.LoadFile()`?